# Inter data center traffic of Google Compute VMs

Tags: google-compute-engine

Does anyone know that if there is a limit on network traffic among VMs in different data centers in Google Compute Engine?
Specifically, are there any performance limits if VMs in different DCs are frequently (every 5 ms) communicating with each other?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that there are some performance limits, but they should be fairly high if you're within the same region. (>100Mbps, possibly >1Gbps) Between regions, bandwidth is likely to be somewhat more variable, but I'd expect it to be >100Mbps on the same continent.

Note that there are also [egress fees](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#network) for traffic between VMs in different GCP zones, so you might want to pay attention to the total data transferred; 130Mbps would be around 1GB every minute, or $6/hour.